# Need app compatible with any version of Macromedia Flash Player ActiveX

Tags: flash

How I can write code which is compatible with any version of Macromedia Flash Player ActiveX (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the first question is, why?  According to the Adobe Flash version demographics, roughly 98% of flash users are 10.1 capable.

[Demographics](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplatformruntimes/statistics.displayTab3.html)

If you **must** have support that far down, I'd suggest working with Actionscript 2.0, which will work with FP 5 and greater.

Best of luck.